# Set jquery mask on a dynamically inserted input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mask

Set jquery mask on a dynamically inserted input?

I'm trying to do it in the down format, but I'm not succeeding.

The new input loses the mask.

Can someone help me with this please.?

```
<div class="control">
<input type="text" name="item_valor" placeholder="Valor" class="input valor" maxlength="255" id="id_item_valor">
</div>
```

.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.valor').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
    });
```

.

```
$(document).on('click', '#addItem', function () {
var newElement = $('.control:last').clone(true);
$('.control:last').after(newElement);
})
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the mask on focus of the input like this

```
$(document).on("focus", ".valor", function() { 
    $(this).mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
  });
```

you can probably remove it from document.ready function and also instead of cloning and appending in 2 lines you can shorten it to 1 line with this

```
$('.control:last').after($('.control:last').clone());
```

here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tv7w3Lku/3/

**Side note**: cloning an element with ID will create multiple elements with same ID which is probably not the best way, you should just stick with class in this case

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Just recall your mask function after each input is added to the DOM.

```
$(document).on('click', '#addItem', function () {
     var newElement = $('.control:last').clone(true);
     $('.control:last').after(newElement);
      $('.valor').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
})
```

Comment: Does not work. In this formed the div is added empty. Thanks for listening.

Comment: @marcelo.delta, I have updated the code to remask all of the valor fields. Try this one.

Comment: I already tested like that and it also did not work. This is complex. Because I think the DOM is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, and discovered the .masked() function will apply the mask to a dynamic value.  Hope this helps:

HTML:

```
<input name="phone" type="text">

<button>insert dynamic value</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name='phone']").mask("(000) 000-0000");
});

$("button").click(function(){
    newPhoneNumber = "1231231234";
    maskedValue = $("input[name='phone']").masked(newPhoneNumber));
    $("input[name='phone']").val(maskedValue);
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qcsf3z0j/4/

and docs: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#getting-a-masked-value-programmatically